# How to check for ID uniqueness on large dataset that can't fit into memory or on a single disk

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, cloud-computing, cloud

Say I have 500MB of memory to work with, but 100 terabytes of IDs I want to generate. I want these IDs (GUIDs) to be randomly selected and applied to records, so they shouldn't appear in order when selected. Also, I have 1 billion petabytes (in this example) of possible IDs, which is way too many to actually generate. So I only select 100 terabytes initially out of the possible space. I'm not sure how many IDs that would be, but say it's on the order of 10^32 or something large (I don't know the exact number). So basically, this is the situation:

1. A gigantic space of possible IDs (10^32, or more precisely I am focusing on the number being 1 billion petabytes, an unreasonably large amount of data).
2. A subset of these IDs which are randomly selected. In this case, 100 terabytes of IDs.
3. A computer that is limited to 500MB or so, so all the possible IDs needed can't possibly fit into memory.
4. The computer only has 10GB of disk space.

The question is how to architect a fast system for generating these IDs.

After some thought my approach was to consider generating a Trie. Say the IDs are 32 characters matching `/[0-9]/`. Then we would generate the equivalent of 100 terabytes in the trie, 1 character at a time. This removes the need of storing duplicate characters by probably a few orders of magnitude of memory. But still it would require about 100 terabytes of memory to construct the trie, so that doesn't work.

So basically in the extreme case where we can't possibly store 100TB on the computer or even on a few external hard drives, we need the "cloud" to solve this. That is, we need to somehow use the cloud to check if the IDs have already been used, and then to generate one if it's not been created or used.

The question is how to optimally do this so it takes the least amount of time to generate all the IDs.

Not looking for answers like "don't worry about duplicates", or "that's too many IDs to generate". I would like to know how to specifically solve this problem.

What I have resorted to is basically:

1. Check in "cloud" database if record exists.
2. If so, try a different value and repeat.
3. If not, then save it to the database.

But this is extremely slow and would take weeks of computer time to run and generate the IDs. It seems like there could be a data structure and algorithm to make this faster.

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using random GUIDS instead of a sequential number? I know guids are a good practice in most cases, but here they seem to be more than a bother than anything else.

Comment: I want to use GUIDs, no other solution.

Comment: I understand that. I'm asking _why_. "Because yes" is the root of a billion different problems on Comp-sci.

Comment: I may have a working suggestion to you, but I need more details about the specific need for the GUID solution and why the hardware is limited like this. With a few tweaks, this might be possible.

Comment: If you use non-random UUIDs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), then you can mathematically prove that you won't generate duplicates. If you have a good source of randomness, you might even be able to prove statistically for random UUIDs that the chance of a collision is negligible even for the number of UUIDs that you want to generate.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau how would I do that with the case of 1 out of 10^32 possible values, where we have a character string composed of 0-9 that is 32 symbols long. Or where do I find more information on how to get started with that, it sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @LokasaMawati Do you _need_ them to be 0-9 with 32 symbols long? This is what bothering me with your question. You have a need that could be solved by small tweaks on your restrictions. We don't know _why_ they exist in the first place, so any attempt to answer this question will be utterly frustrating.

Comment: The number doesn't have to be entirely random, just _seem_ random. So perhaps out of the 10^32 values we select every 3rd or 4th value and mathematically then we have a smaller set and guaranteed unique.

Comment: Yes they need to be 0-9 with 32 symbols, that is the design constraints of the system (UI and UX). They can be any symbol set customized by the designers (like all capital letters at 75 symbols long, or 6 letters AEIOUY at 23 symbols long, etc.), but they _cannot_ be the default hex symbols or other default/uncontrolled symbol sets.

Comment: Hm. I think I have an idea.

Comment: If there is a case to be made for having it be a certain length, like multiple of 2 or power of 2 type thing, that would be interesting to know and I could work with that. But being more general than that would be better.

Comment: _Not looking for answers like  ...  "that's too many IDs to generate"._ -- You've already said 1 yottabytes' worth of IDs too many to generated and chopped it back to 100 terabytes.  What makes 1 YB too many and 100 TB okay?  More importantly, what's the use case for generating such a large set of IDs ahead of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the numbers to *appear* to be random, I have an idea.

The following is just a concept. It is by no means the only (or correct!) way of doing this, and you'll need to tweak it a bit to fit your needs. If you want to use this, use it as a starting point only.

---

You start with a single arbitrarily-sized number-storing variable set to an arbitrary number. That will be your seed.

Let's use "123456789" as an example.

If you consider our seed an array of characters = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}, we can use a simple composition to get back a seemingly random number by just swapping those around in a fixed manner:

```
 ID1 = s[2] + s[6] + s[0] + s[1] + s[8] + s[3] + s[5] + s[4] + s[7];
```

You'll end up with the number "371294658", which *appears* to be random. After you generate this ID, just add 7 (or any large odd number of your liking) to your seed:

```
Seed = "123456796"
```

And swap those around again to get your next ID, using the same positions swaps as before:

```
ID2 = "371264659"
```

And so on.

```
Seed = "123456803"
ID3 = 381234650.
```

If you look at the IDs at a glance, they appear to be close, but the order in which they were generate isn't evident at all without further examination.

```
ID1 = 371294658
ID2 = 371264659
ID3 = 381234650
```

The numbers are going up and down, there are gaps between then, and so on. While not impossible (nor hard) for a clever attacker to figure out what we are doing here, for most purposes it provides a non-sequential, unique number for you to play with, and it is a pretty fast way to do so. More importantly, it allows your backend to "unpack" this ID to restore the original sequential number if the need ever arises. More so, it creates the possibility of checking for tampering by looking at IDs that don't follow the generator's rules.

---

I made a small prototype of this thing on LinqPad, using a rather large number as a "salt". Look at the results I got:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This smells of homework or an interview question, especially the "10 GB of disk space" part. But here goes:

1. Generate your IDs using a cryptographically-strong random number generator.
2. Use your 10GB of disk space as a bitmapped Bloom filter:

   - Hash the generated ID and mod 80G (8 bits per byte)
   - Determine the status of the bit corresponds to this value.
   - If the bit is clear, mark it and use the ID
   - If the bit is already set, go back to step 1

Comment: Definitely not homework or interview question, I literally want to generate these IDs on my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is generate an ordered list of guid's and then randomly reading from that ordered list, marking any id you used and skipping id's that have been taken.
Whenever you pick an already used id, skip to the next.

The making of the ordered list is an O(n) operation and the picking a random item is an O(1) operation.

If you want to generate id's randomly and check for uniqueness it's going to be probably an O(n log(n)) operation, which will take quite long considering your amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

If the ID's only need to appear random to a casual observer, then I would use an algorithm like this:

1. Sequentially generate numbers (remember where you left off in a persistent manner, so a reboot doesn't restart the sequence)
2. Use the last generated number to create a Name-Based UUID according to [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). The hashing that takes place as part of the UUID creation will make the UUID appear to be randomly generated.
3. Present the UUID to the user as a 32-character string with symbols chosen from an alphabet with 16 symbols of your choice. There should be a 1-to-1 correspondence between the symbols in your alphabet and the standard hexadecimal alphabet, but that does not have to be apparent.

Comment: Follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3217114/how-to-select-numbers-from-large-set-in-such-a-way-that-they-appear-random-yet-a.

Answer (score 1):

Use a **UUID**:

```
UUID id = UUID.randomUID();
```

This probably is already unique. But you can hold the most recent UUIDs by timestamp:

```
long timestamp = id.timestamp();
```

and check those for uniqueness. Estimate the throughput for the size of the latest moment. The latest timestamp must be persistent.

An other approach would be to have a **file** with a bit for every id, and do **random access**, maybe using one or more **memory mapped buffers**.

Comment: I don't want to use UUIDs as per the constraints listed, and this probably wouldn't work at the scale I'm describing.

Answer (score 1):

These requirements seem arbitrary and your goals are unclear but one approach could be to use a secure [PRGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) and a [Bloom Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).  A bloom filter will use a very small fraction of the space required for a trie.  The main concern here is your false positive rate. There's a bit of homework here to figure out the size of the filter and your hash functions.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and extremely efficient solution requiring virtually zero storage:
Keep a count of the number of IDs issued so far, *n*. Generate the high order bits of each ID as a pseudo-random number; and set the low order bits to *n*.

All IDs will be guaranteed unique, and their ordering will be random.